# new >> how would i read a file that has 3 columns and each column contains 100 numbers into an array?

Tags: c++, file, arrays

```
int exam1[100];// array that can hold 100 numbers for 1st column 
int exam2[100];// array that can hold 100 numbers for 2nd column 
int exam3[100];// array that can hold 100 numbers for 3rd column  

int main() 
{ 
  ifstream infile;   

  int num; 
  infile.open("example.txt");// file containing numbers in 3 columns 
     if(infile.fail()) // checks to see if file opended 
    { 
      cout << "error" << endl; 
    } 
       while(!infile.eof()) // reads file to end of line 
      { 
         for(i=0;i<100;i++); // array numbers less than 100 
           { 
        while(infile >> [exam]); // while reading get 1st array or element 
            ???// how will i go read the next number 
            infile >> num; 
          } 
      } 
  infile.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Note that `void main` is not legal C++ - it needs to be `int main`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int exam1[100];// array that can hold 100 numbers for 1st column 
int exam2[100];// array that can hold 100 numbers for 2nd column 
int exam3[100];// array that can hold 100 numbers for 3rd column  

int main() // int main NOT void main
{ 
  ifstream infile;   

  int num = 0; // num must start at 0
  infile.open("example.txt");// file containing numbers in 3 columns 
     if(infile.fail()) // checks to see if file opended 
    { 
      cout << "error" << endl; 
      return 1; // no point continuing if the file didn't open...
    } 
       while(!infile.eof()) // reads file to end of *file*, not line
      { 
         infile >> exam1[num]; // read first column number
         infile >> exam2[num]; // read second column number
         infile >> exam3[num]; // read third column number

         ++num; // go to the next number

         // you can also do it on the same line like this:
         // infile >> exam1[num] >> exam2[num] >> exam3[num]; ++num;
      } 
  infile.close(); 

  return 0; // everything went right.
}
```

I assume you always have 3 numbers per line. If you know the exact number of lines, replace the while with a `for` from 0 to the number of lines.

Comment: Well, true, but he did try and the problem is pretty small. He probably just didn't know that you can string multiple read operations that way.

Comment: is this the right syntex for reading a file. i am new and i think i get the idea but im not 100 percent sure u know?

Comment: Don't do this: while(!infile.eof()). The basic anti-pattern for reading a file. num will now be 1 to large.

Answer (score 3):

Rule # 1 about reading data from a file:  don't trust the contents of the file.  You never know with absolute certainty what is in the file until you've read it

That said, one correct way to read *lines* of data from a file, where each line is composed of multiple whitespace-delimited fields would be to use a combination of `getline` and `stringstream`:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    int a, b, c;
    if (ss >> a >> b >> c)
    {
        // Add a, b, and c to their respective arrays
    }
}
```

In English, we get each line from the file stream using `getline`, then parse the line into three integers using a `stringstream`.  This allows us to be certain that each line is formatted correctly.

We check to ensure the extraction of the integers succeeded *before* we add them to the arrays to ensure that the arrays always have only valid data.

There is other error handling that might be desirable:

- In the example, if extraction of the integers from the line fails, we just ignore that line; it could be a good idea to add logic to abort the process or report an error.
- After we get three integers, we ignore the rest of the line; it might be a good idea to add checks to ensure that there is no more data on the line after the required integers, depending on how strict the file's formatting needs to be.
- After we finish reading the file, we should test to be sure `eof()` is set and not `fail()` or `bad()`; if one of those two flags is set, some error occurred when reading the file.

Comment: whoa! i dont even know about stringstream is i am a beginner. is there away achieving this another way? so are you saying std::string line will read lines and not whitespaces? and then the numbers i read will save as a string in the variable line?
 what is the if statement i dont really understand that one and maybe the other one too

Comment: @user:  The `while` loop reads each line of the file as a string into `line`.  Then the `if` statement using the `stringstream` splits the line and parses it as three `int` variables.  You can then copy the `int` variables into the arrays.  There are many ways to solve this problem in C++; I think this is by far the simplest method to do it with correct error handling.

Comment: ok does it also read the numbers if they are less than 3 maybe just one number?

Comment: @user:  No, because that wasn't what you specified.  It can be easily modified to handle that case, however, with a little research on streams and how extraction works.

Comment: don't forget add '#include <sstream>' for   std::stringstream ss(line);